# Why `my_do_fork` and `post_handler` are executed but `pre_handler` isn't?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, jprobe, kprobe

I have used `jprobe` in a kernel module and everything works just fine. except the fact that the `pre_handler` is not executed.

```
static struct jprobe my_jprobe = {
         .entry               = my_do_fork,
         .kp = {
                 .symbol_name = "do_fork",
                 .pre_handler = pre_handler,
                 .post_handler = post_handler,
         },
 };
```

Why `my_do_fork` and `post_handler` are executed but `pre_handler` isn't?

Comment: Maybe `sysctl -w debug.kprobes_optimization=n` helps...